# Dynamic Connection String for multi-tenancy In EF Core and Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant

My question is pretty straight forward and there is some stuff out there but a lot seems to be outdated or not answer my question.

As of now, I have my connection string inside the appsettings.json and setting up the database connection as follows:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
    options => options
        .UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions< MyDbContext > options) : base(options) { }
    ...
}
```

However, I would like to give my users the option to dynamically choose a database by providing the connection string on login. The user therefore provides username, password and connection string when logging into the application.

Is something like that possible? If yes, please let me know how to do this. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Will do, thanks. @John

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you'll probably have to look up a multi-tenant configuration for Entity Framework.

Comment: Maybe something [along these lines](https://medium.com/swlh/entity-framework-core-multitenancy-112d82cd89c6).

Comment: You're asking about *multi-tenancy*, not dynamic connection strings. That's not something that's solved by using different connection strings. [Check this blog post for example](https://medium.com/swlh/entity-framework-core-multitenancy-112d82cd89c6) which explains the various options (table, schema, database or server multitenancy) and how each one can be achieved using DbCommandInterceptor

Comment: Thanks for the great article! I will look into it.